# Why should I omit "like" from "...would ask like this question: why..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

> Many people would ask ***like*** this question: why am I here?

One of my friend told me that I should omit like, but he didn't tell my why.
Is the sentence with like grammatically or meaningfully correct or not?

And if i should cross ***like*** out, why I must do that?

What I meant by "like" is maybe they would ask themselves a question identical to this question or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend understood *like* in your sentence as the discourse marker employed in informal English either to keep a sentence moving while you gather your thoughts or to emphasize what follows. This *like* is not employed in written English (except of course in dialogue).

That's really the only interpretation *like* will bear in this position. 'Lexical' *like*, which you tell is what you intended to express, is an adjective used to compare its 'head' (the nominal which it modifies) to some other entity which follows *like*. That second entity is what comes after *like* as its complement.

> **a** <sub>HEAD</sub>**man** ***like*** <sub>COMP</sub>**this man**

So when you write

> ... ask like this question ...

you have an adjective phrase, with *like* and its complement *this question*—but you don't have a **head**, a nominal which the phrase modifies.

What you need to do is not delete *like* but add the head:

> Many people would ask <sub>HEAD</sub>***a question*** like this question: why am I here?

And that can be expressed more simply like this:

> Many people would ask a question like this one: why am I here?

Observe that this is not simply a matter of moving *question*. There are **two** *questions* involved here: the question which people ask and the question which the first question is compared to.